# Why is Microsoft Windows Update (KB5003220) breaking authentication to my File Share

Tags: windows, windows-update

We have a file share on our SAN using CIFS/SMB protocol. Immediately upon applying this particular Windows Update (KB5003220), authentication to the file share breaks. Does anyone know what causes this?

Further testing has shown that the file share is still accessible using host name after the update, but not using the IP address - which is how most of our users had the network drive mapped. Why is this? Normally I would think IP would always work and host name only if users can resolve DNS.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what causes this?

KB5003220 has most likely nothing to do with this, because it fixes some WPF stuff. It does not touch SMB oder CIFS.

Also, Windows Server 2008/2012, Windows 7/8 are out of support and should no longer be used in production systems.

> Normally I would think IP would always work and host name only if
> users can resolve DNS.

Normally, you *want* to use the FQDN. Otherwise the client will not be able to secure it's SMB channels.